# Play bar 7 of Mikrokosmos piece "In Dorian Mode"

Tags: piano, mikrokosmos

I'm learning piece 32 "In Dorian Mode" of Bartok's Mikrokosmos, and I am puzzled by something at bar 7.  Left and right hand staves are both written in the treble clef, and the last note of bar 7 is the same G for both hands

[image]

The piano does not allow to play this G twice simultaneously.  How am I supposed to play this?

Answer (score 1):

No need to play it twice.  Both voices just happen to use the same note at that point.  You can choose which hand you wish to use.  Or you could play the G using a finger from both hands at the same time, if that helped musically, but the result would pretty much be the same, so no real need to do that.